# 黒い VS 黒 What is the difference between them?

Tags: adjectives, nouns

I was wondering why the translation for a black cat is 黒猫 and not 黒い猫. It has come to my understanding that 黒い is an adjictive, so that's what should be used when modifying a noun. While 黒 is just a noun.

Comment: In the specific case you mentioned, it's because it's a compound word. It's not just a cat that is black (黒い猫 - very much a valid phrase, still), but a **black cat**. A cat defined by the fact that it's black.

Answer (score 5):

In short, it's because 黒猫 is an established *single word* made of two kanji. As you know, [a black cat has its own cultural significance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_cat) in western countries, and this fact is known to Japanese people, too. Someone in the past must have felt it deserved a dedicated single word. It's similar to English words like *windmill*, *airplane*, *keyboard*, etc. 白猫 is also used, but other combinations like 茶猫 or 赤猫 are not common.

黒い猫 means a cat which is black. It's always grammatical to say so, but it may sound a bit clumsy and it may not carry the connotation the word 黒猫 normally has.